# Верно ли употреблено тире?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Верно ли составлено предложение-реплика? — "Вы какой купить хотите **—** с фильтром или без?".
2. Верно ли употреблён вопросительный знак и тире в тексте?

Answer (score 1):

Вы какОй купить хотите — с фИльтром или бЕз?

Знаки поставлены верно, можно добавить **комментарий** (объяснение грамматики и интонации).

Здесь вопросительное местоимение "какой" поясняется однородным рядом из двух определений, стоящим в конце предложения. Для  структуры данного предложения больше подходит тире, тогда **логическим ударением удобно выделить** местоимение "какой" (интонация присоединительная).

**Сравнить:** Вы какОй (предмет) хотели бы купИть: с фИльтром или бЕз? В этом предложении  можно сделать **предупредительную паузу** и обозначить ее **двоеточием.**

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, "какой" - это своеобразное обобщающее слово для двух последующих несогласованных определений "с фильтром" и "без". Поэтому по правилам, я думаю,  следовало бы поставить двоеточие. Но, если рассматривать "с фильтром" и "без" как своеобразное уточнение (какой именно?), тогда можно поставить тире.